# Deploying and Using a Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I followed the app script guide to [create a menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) for my spreadsheet.
I was tested during development in the spreadsheet running it by going to:

> Tools -> Script manager...

But now I want to permanently add it to the spreadsheet, but I don't know hot to deploy it.

I deployed it as a webapp, but when I click the test link i get:

> Script function not found: doGet

I can not find documentation to complete that doGet function.

Any help on the last step to use my first Google App Script?

Answer (score 0):

if the function that create your menu is called onOpen(e) it should automatically do the job for you when the document is opened, you don't need to publish the app or anything like that.
But in order to be executed the onOpen function must not call personnal data for the user this function onOpen (when triggered automatically, when you open the sheet) has limited rights:
in the doc https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus,
it say:

> Warning: Note that the add-on menu sample above compares the
>   e.authMode property to values from the ScriptApp.AuthMode enum. This
>   is because an add-on that has not been used in the current document
>   runs its onOpen(e) function with severe restrictions, as explained in
>   the guide to the add-on authorization lifecycle. If your published
>   add-on fails to add its menu items, look in the browser's JavaScript
>   console to see if an error was thrown, then examine your script to see
>   whether the onOpen(e) function or global variables call services that
>   aren't allowed in AuthMode.NONE.

Comment: let me explain my problem in other words:
If I open the spreadsheet I have to manually go to Tools -> Script manager and select my script every time I want to use my spreadsheet.

Comment: @Kummo, I'm sorry, but you are not telling what's the expected comportment here, it's just the description of the actual comportment. For what I understood: In the sentence "But now I want to permanently add it to the spreadsheet" did you mean A) add it to all the spreadsheet you've got, or did you mean B) you want it to be called every time you open the spreadsheet? case A create a library (but anyway you'll have to deploy it on every spreadsheet, case B rename the function that create the menu (and that only create the menu, the function must not do anything else than the menu) in "onOpen"

Comment: No I'm sorry cause this maybe is a silly question but let me try again: This app script that I'm done with the development I want to added permanently to my spreadsheet, that way all the users that I've already shared it are able to use the new menu. Do you know what I mean? It like deploy in "production"